# Changing/modifying selector assigned to UINavigationBar.backItem

Tags: iphone

and for some reasons I don't want to use leftBarButtonItem. That will be my second priority.
FYI I'm creating my own UINavigationController class, so that I can accommodate a image on top of the navigationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I think I found a way out using the UINaivgationBarDelegate methods:

```
- (void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
```

Please still respond if you've a better idea

Comment: I'm committing the code at http://code.google.com/p/custom-navigation-controller/source/checkout if somebody needs that too